# Why do people actually go to other Q&A communities for coding questions other than StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

When I search for answers for specific coding questions, I always bump into threads in various tech forums, for example, here's what I found for a C# question:

- [Thread in bytes.com forum](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/262265-web-services-custom-classes)
- [Thread in asp.net forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1345108.aspx?Trying%20to%20consume%20Web%20Service%20class%20returns%20a%20class%20C%20)
- [Thread in p2p.wrox.com forum](http://p2p.wrox.com/c/35391-custom-classes-web-services.html)

I was always wondering - why, given the existence of the much more superior StackOverflow network, people would still go to other messy/ugly/miserable/non-user-friendly Q&A communities to ask coding questions.

I know variety is probably a good thing, but it really bothers me when seeing a critical question of which answers I would really like to read through but couldn't do so smoothly because it's formatted horribly and is ruined with endless quotings as a result of being presented in a bad platform.

If you are one of those people who still ask coding questions in other forums, I would like to hear your reason.

Comment: All three of your cited examples are several years old; Stack Overflow wasn't even around in 2005.  We don't accept some kinds of questions, especially those that are overtly subjective.  Users have no choice but to ask those questions elsewhere.

Comment: Just have a search for your ugly/miserable/non-user-friendly in combination with "Stack Overflow". Some people truly don't like (or even hate) Stack Overflow. We've had users profess the superiority of several sites over SO. To each their own.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've started to go to other sites because SO is getting too full of itself.  I've had many times when I was stuck, asked a question, and get shot down because my question wasn't properly formatted, or because other users automatically assume that you're an idiot and give you the simplest answer possible (even if you carefully described how you've already tried that).  Even looking at the sidebar while I write this, there's many questions about 'Disallowing questions for people below a certain reputation'; or 'Should we add RTFM to the list of close reasons?'; or 'why is the quality of questions diminishing?'.

I'm a smart guy, and have experience in many areas of programming.  I also like to try new things, and would like to be able to come to SO for help when I get stuck doing something new.  But here's the thing: SO is hostile to novices.  It's not a welcoming place.  Many answerers want to dismiss you immediately, and never come back.

Comment: It seems that there are conflicting ideas about what StackOverflow should be: Most users treat it as a general "programmers helping programmers" bazaar (sometimes you need an extra pair of eyes for debugging, etc.), and uninitiated beginning programmers even treat it like structured IRC, but the site staff and a lot of the more experienced members (who tire of repetition) want it to be more like a searchable cathedral of unique but widely applicable design questions or questions about the nuances of a language or technology...you know, for posterity, and mind the crystal chandeliers. ;)

Comment: @Mike S, Which is fine. But if StackOverflow becomes exclusive instead of inclusive, it will die. Not immediately, slowly, but surely. It will do so by its own demise. I'd like to see some end to overreactive moderation. But having been around this site and others so long now, and watched some of these sites die the exact same way, I'm starting to think it is just human nature. Eventually all of the mods will drive away even the very best users of the site, and it will simply fade away from relevance. I've some ideas for solutions to this, but I can't see such a thing ever being implemented.

Comment: _But here's the thing: SO is hostile to novices._ I disagree. I'm quite new here (a year and a half using SO), and have never faced any kind of hostility, even when asking things that would look trivial to the majority (when I started working with ASP.NET MVC and left WebForms). The whole point is to spend a bit of time and read the recommendations. Like @MikeS said, people still come here thinking it's a "How to" site, or a site with a collection of "Tutorials".

Comment: I have multiple questions that had never been asked before, show research, are polite, have an accepted answer, and for which I lost reputation in posting.  I've had questions get marked as duplicates when the first lines are links to those duplicate questions followed by an explanation of why the answer didn't work.  At this point, I can no longer ask anything. The people here always depress me by being so unkind for so little reason even when the question is within the guidelines and unique.

Answer (score 17):

SO is not designed to be everything to everyone.  It has specifically narrowed its scope, quite a bit more than its competition.  This has made it more attractive to a lot of subject experts, because questions are of higher quality, and tools are given to those users to fix or remove problematic questions.

Many people don't know how to ask good questions, or are unwilling to spend the (often considerable) time to write good question.  Many people don't know how to, or are unwilling to, write quality answers.  Many people aren't comfortable accepting feedback of any kind on the quality of their contributions.  These people are better served on other sites that don't have the quality standards that SO does.

And then of course there are scope issues.  There are questions that are inherently good questions but that SO has simply removed from its scope, in order to more effectively answer those questions that is has kept *in* scope.  Other sites may have a broader scope, a different scope, or a narrower scope, each of which can potentially be more attractive for certain users.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is very well-rounded.

Comment: This answer looks like a SO ad

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer for myself.  Being inexperienced in a subject and maybe not having English as your first language sometimes makes it difficult to communicate your needs.  Many times questions have simply been downvoted with no explanation - then you are threatened with being banned from asking.  Quite honestly I am scared to ask anything anymore and considering leaving.  If people take the time to read the question and consider the askers real needs it is quite simple, but not as simple as simply clicking downvote.  I have seen many questions that are marked as off topic etc yet some people still provide an answer that helps the asker.  And rejected as opinon based?  Most answers ARE opinion based or there would only be one answer.  How else do you get ideas when you are new.

Comment: Most answers are opinion base because there can be more than one way to solve an issue? ... now I wonder if you _really_ know what "opinion based" actually means.

Comment: @Tom - thanks for the feed back - I was basically saying there may be more than one way to solve a problem and the solution offered may vary.  Really I feel most answers reflect the opinion of the expert answering will be based on the experts opinion that is answering - that is why so many questions get several different answers and several of these answers may be upvoted depending on the opinion of others. Realistically, if someone gives their answer by definition it must be their opinion that it is the correct answer.

Comment: Your English seems just fine, by the way.